# Type conversion for NSRect parameters

Tags: swift, implicit-conversion

Am I doing something wrong, or is Swift supposed to be written with constant conversions? For instance, I want to define an `NSRect` to draw a circle, and I have already defined an `NSPoint` that will be its centre, also I have a radius of `Float` type that will define width and height, but it should be multiplied by `Int` scale before, so I do it like this:

```
let objectRect = NSRect(x: center.x - radius*scale ...
```

I get a warning that I cannot multiply `Int` by `Float`. Okay, now it looks like this:

```
let objectRect = NSRect(x: center.x - radius*Float(scale) ...
```

Now this part is fine, but another warning says that `Float` cannot be subtracted from `CGFloat`. Another conversion:

```
let objectRect = NSRect(x: Float(center.x) - radius*Float(scale) ...
```

Looks awful already, but to top the cake last warning states that NSRect does not accept Float, so I need to convert it to Double.

Answer (score 1):

Do it just once. And as commented below use `CGFloat` right away:

```
let objectRect = NSRect(x: CGFloat(center.x) - radius* CGFloat(scale) ...
```

Coming from scripting languages the Swift type system can be annoying. However, you get used to it.

Comment: Although this will silence the errors on OPs device (which is apparently 64 bit), it will cause the same problem on a 32 bit device. In short, use CGFloat.

Comment: Ya, I use `CGFLoat` almost everywhere. Will change it.

Comment: But why don't they do it implicitly? Some conceptual reasons?

Comment: @RomaValcer: “Values are never implicitly converted to another type. If you need to convert a value to a different type, explicitly make an instance of the desired type.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/de/jEUH0.l – So yes, this is one of Swift's key concepts.

Comment: @MartinR this makes code somewhat harder to read, in my opinion.